# The finite generation of $M$, to conclude $M$ is Noetherian (when $R$ is Noetherian).

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, artinian

We know the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** *Let $R$ be a Noetherian/Artinian ring and $M$ an $R$-module. If $M$ is finitely generated, then the $R$-module $M$ is Noetherian module.*

I was wondering if the condition of "finitely generation" of $M$ is necessary. And for this purpose if tried to find an example.

**Examples.**

1. We consider the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Q$, which is  the abelian group $(\Bbb Q,+).$ The ring $\Bbb Z$ is a Noetherian ring, the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Q$ is *not* finitely generated (since the abelian group $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is *not* finitely generated) and of course $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Q$ is *not* a Noetherian module (since itself is again a submodule, *not* f.g.). Is this idea in the right way?
2. But $\Bbb Z$ is *not* Artinian, to consider an example for this case. So, what if we take a field $K$ and construct the $K\!$-module $K[X]$? What can we conclude for this case? Is $K[X]$ Noetherian/Artinian as a $K$-module and why?
3. Any other ideas?

*Thank you.*

Comment: So, to be clear, you are asking "If $M$ is Noetherian, is it finitely generated?" and not "Can I drop the condition of 'finitely generated' from the proposition?"  At first glance, it looks like the latter, but after further reading the former one (which makes more sense) is the likely one.

Answer (score 3):

Any Noetherian module is finitely generated, so the condition is clearly necessary for a module being Noetherian.

Artinian modules can be infinitely generated. The simplest example is the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group).

Your $K[X]$ cannot be Artinian, because vector spaces over a field are Artinian if and only if they're Noetherian, that is, finite dimensional.

Comment: Nice example, thank you, I 'll check this group!

Answer (score 2):

For a commutative ring, we have that an artinian ring is noetherian, this by the Hopkins-Levitzki theorem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopkins%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem

If $A$ is a noetherian ring then $A[x]$ is a noetherian ring, but $A[x]$ is not noetherian as an $A$-module.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem

In general for a non zero commutative ring $A$, $A[x]$ is not a noetherian $A$-module. Consider the ideals $I_n=\sum_{k=0}^nAx^k$. So we have a strict ascending chain  of $A$-submodules in $A[x]$. So you have the ascending chain $I_0\subset I_1\subset i_2\subset\dots$, so have found a non statioanary ascending chain.Showing that $A[x]$ is not noetherian as $A$-module.

To see that is no artinian as  an a $A$-module, we build a descending chain given by $J_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty Ax^k$. So you have a strict descending chain of $A$-modules. Showing that $A[x]$ is not artinian as $A$-module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean the descending chain $\langle 1_K \rangle \supseteq \langle X \rangle \supseteq \langle X^2 \rangle \supseteq  \dots$? So $K-$module $K[X]$ is *not* Artinian?

Comment: The chain you mention is only a chain if you consider what you generate as $K[x]$-modules, that's it, as an ideal of $K[x]$. But as you want it as $K$-module, they are no in general $K[x]$-modules.

Comment: Do you mean that my idea is valid only for the $K-$module $K[X]$ and *not* for $K[X]-$module $K[X]$?

Comment: Viceversa, you idea is valid for $K[x]$ as $K[x]$-module. But is no valid for $K[x]$ as $K$-module.

Comment: It's ok, I understood. In $K-$module $K[X]$, it is $\langle X \rangle \nsupseteq \langle X^2 \rangle $ since if otherwise, $X^2 \in \langle X \rangle  \iff \exists r\in K:\ X^2 = r\cdot X \implies  \deg (X^2)= \deg (r \cdot X)$, contradicion. Right?

Comment: Exactly, you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

No, $K[X]$ is not artinian, because a commutative artinian ring has Krull dimension $0$.

Actually, for commutative rings, artinian $\iff$ noetherian and of Krull dimension $0$.

However, you may consider its field of fractions $K(X)$, which is artinian, being a field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why $K[X]$ is *not* a Noetherian $K-$module?

Comment: Because it is not finitely generated.

Comment: We know that $K[X]$ is a $K-$vector space $\iff K[X]$ is a $K-$module as we know. And $K[X]=\langle 1_K,X,X^2,\dots,X^n,\dots \rangle$ is not finitely generated. It's ok for Noetherian. Can we prove $K[X]$ is *not* Artinian without use of Hopkins' Theorems (maybe only with definition)?

Comment: What do you call Hopkins' theorems?

Comment: Sorry, I did a typo. I meant Hopkins-Levitzki theorem and it's the second sentence that you wrote (with Krull dimension). :)

Comment: It is enough to mention the descending chain: $\;(X)\supsetneq (X^2)\supsetneq (X^3)\supsetneq  \dots$.

Comment: I just wrote the same thought on a comment above. Thank you!

Comment: Oh! yes. I saw it, but I was doing several things simultaneously, and I forgot.

Comment: Is this chain valid for $K-$module $K[X]$?

Comment: Which chain exactly?

Comment: $(X) ⊋ (X^2) ⊋ (X^3) ⊋ \dots $ in $K-$module $K[X]$

Comment: The decreasing chain of monomials is valid, yes. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: I m trying to sum up taking into consideration all the answers. But @Frank above claimed that this chain is not valid and I am confused :( 
(also I apologize for the long comments)

Comment: I see. Maybe I misunderstood your question. What I had in mind is that $K[X]$ is not an artinian *ring*.

Comment: So, this claim is valid *only* to conclude that  $K[X]-$module $K[X]$ is not Artinian module $\iff $  the ring $K[X]$ is not Artinian?

Comment: More exactly, $\Longleftarrow$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90643/discussion-between-chris-and-bernard).

Comment: All dependend of what you consider by $\langle \rangle$. As I said below, if you considered it as $K[x]$-module generated, you have a descending chain. If it as $K$-module is not a descending chain.

Comment: Where did I consider $\langle\rangle$? And why would the same chain be descending or not depending on the underlying structure taken into consideration?